# matplotlib: histogram and bin labels

Tags: rotation, matplotlib, histogram, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm trying to plot a histogram with bar chart, and I'm having difficulties figuring out how to align the x-axis labels with the actual bins. The code below generates the following plot: [image: Bar chart]

as you can see, the end of each x-label is not aligned to the center of its bin.  The way i'm thinking about this is: when i apply a 45-degree rotation, the label pivots around its geometrical center.  I was wondering if it's possible to move the pivot up to the top of the label. (Or simply translate all the labels slightly left.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#data
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.rand(5)
names = ['A:GBC_1233','C:WERT_423','A:LYD_342','B:SFS_23','D:KDE_2342']

ax = plt.subplot(111)
width=0.3
bins = map(lambda x: x-width/2,range(1,len(data)+1))
ax.bar(bins,data,width=width)
ax.set_xticks(map(lambda x: x, range(1,len(data)+1)))
ax.set_xticklabels(names,rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(names,rotation=45, rotation_mode="anchor", ha="right")
```

The output is:

[image]