# Matplotlib histogram label text crowded

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm making a histogram in matplotlib and the text label for each bin are overlapping on each other like this:
[image]

I tried to rotate the labels on the x-axis by following [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938532/matplotlib-histogram-and-bin-labels)

```
cuisine_hist = plt.hist(train.cuisine, bins=100)
cuisine_hist.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

But I get error message `'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'`. Why? How do I solve this problem? Alternatively, how can I "transpose" the plot so the labels are on the vertical axis?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I lumped both answers in one example:

```
# create figure and ax objects, it is a good practice to always start with this
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# then plot histogram using axis
# note that you can change orientation using keyword
ax.hist(np.random.rand(100), bins=10, orientation="horizontal")

# get_xticklabels() actually gets you an iterable, so you need to rotate each label
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(45)
```

It produces the graph with rotated x-ticks and horizontal histogram.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `plt.hist` is not what you use to run the function `set_xticklabels`:

What's running that function is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`, which you can get from here:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cuisine_hist = ax.hist(train.cuisine, bins=100)
ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

From the "help" of plt.hist:

```
Returns
-------
n : array or list of arrays
    The values of the histogram bins. See *normed* or *density*

bins : array
    The edges of the bins. ...

patches : list or list of lists
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html) might be helpful since it is about rotating labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6]
labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Bogs', 'Slogs']

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
# You can specify a rotation for the tick labels in degrees or with keywords.
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
# Pad margins so that markers don't get clipped by the axes
plt.margins(0.2)
# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of tick-labels
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

so I think

```
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
```

is the important line right here.

Answer (score 0):

just this simple line would do the trick

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```